# json data for/in python unittests

Tags: python, json, unit-testing

I'm writing an ORM-like library for Mongo. I've written some models, and want to make sure that they and the machinery that supports them are correct, so I'd like to write unit tests for them. I figured the best way to do that would be to simply write out some test data as JSON, then pass them to my models and see if the valid data is considered valid and the invalid data as invalid.

My question is where to put that data: it seems like a lot of non-`TestCase` stuff to put in `test_models.py`, but adding a separate `test_data_for_models.json` contributes its own headaches (versioning, etc.)

Which is the more recommended/idiomatic? Bear in mind I don't really need to *generate* any data--I'll likely just adapt data that's already in the db--I'm just unsure where to put it.

Comment: If it is just a small amount of data, put it in the Python source code directly.  If it is larger amounts of data, place resource files with the JSON inside besides your source code.  This way they will get versioned just like your source code, which most likely is what you will want.

Comment: @Alfe but that's my issue--versioning additional files is better than _not_ versioning them, but still allows for the test data getting out of sync with the tests.

Comment: I don't see any way that would really prevent them coming out of sync.  As soon as there is more than one file involved (no matter if source/data or source/source), there can be inconsistencies, so unless the data is so small that it could be part of the source file itself, it must be in a different one, and then the problem can arise.  You *will* need to ensure that all files are on matching versions (that has nothing to do with the question of JSON data), I don't see any other option.